# ExtJS - Change field value without firing the "change" event

Tags: extjs

I'm writing a function in a `ViewController` which will reset all of the fields in a complex `View`. This view is using ExtJS 5 two-way data binding with a `ViewModel`. That's how I'm reseting the fields:

```
clearFields: function() {
    var vm = this.getViewModel();

    vm.set('name', '');
    vm.set('address', '');
    vm.set('port', '');
    vm.set('active', false);
    vm.set('dynamic', false);
    vm.set('bandwidthOptimization', true);
    vm.set('reverse', false);
    vm.set('timeout', 60);
    vm.set('camerasEnabled', 1);
    vm.set('username', '');
    vm.set('password', '');
    vm.set('vendorGuid', '');
    vm.set('modelGuid', '');
    vm.set('subscriber', '');
    vm.set('event', '');
    vm.set('partition', '');
    vm.set('instructions', '');
}
```

But each time I use the `set` method, it fires the `change` event of its field, which then is captured back by the controller and do other interactions with the page that are not wanted in this case. So I need to suppress this event from being triggered temporarily. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were setting values on the fields directly (i.e. not via a viewmodel), perhaps you could use [`setRawValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-setRawValue). But if you need to keep doing it the way you quoted, then here is a solution:

In order to prevent a field from firing the `change` event, its private [`suspendCheckChange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-property-suspendCheckChange) property needs to be greater than 0. Therefore you could implement a method to walk through your fields and increase the property before doing your reset, and  then, once reset is done, get the property value back where it was. Example:

```js
suspendChange: function(suspend) {
    var fields = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('field', this.getView()),
        i = 0;
    for (; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (suspend) {
            fields[i].suspendCheckChange++:
        } else {
            fields[i].suspendCheckChange--;
        }
    }
},
clearFields: function() {
    this.suspendChange(true);
    // do reset stuff
    this.suspendChange(false);
}
```

Comment: Suspending the field `change` event would be better, since `suspendCheckChange` is private.

Comment: It works! @EvanTrimboli How can I suspend the event?